# Self-imposed try/catch for unwanted integers

Tags: c++, exception

Try and catch statements are easy for actual exceptions, but how might I write a try/catch for a self-imposed restriction?

For example, if I am getting an integer from cin that I want to be either 2,4, or 7, and anything else to print "That number is not valid" and try again, how would this get written in c++?

Comment: Definitely *not* with exceptions.  You want a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Adam Rosenfield is right: exceptions should be reserved for *exceptional* situations -- i.e., things you don't expect to happen (or at least not very often). A user entering bad data is expected to happen -- frequently.

Since you always want to read the input at least once, this is a situation where a do/while loop makes sense:

```
do { 
    std::cin >> number;
} while (number != 2 && number != 4 && number != 7);
```

Comment: The problem is, "exceptional" means different things to different people. I like the boost error and exception handling guidelines, which boils down to, "Use exceptions for error handling if you want stack unwinding." http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html For example, boost.program_options throws an exception on invalid input (which presumably came from a user passing in command line arguments).

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do this using a simple `while` loop:

```
while (true) {
    int value = /* ... read a number ... */
    if (value == 2 || value == 4 || value == 7) break;

    /* ... report an error ... */
}
```

You are correct that you shouldn't be using try/catch here.  Those are heavyweight primitives for dealing with truly unrecoverable errors.  In this case, this simple lightweight loop should work just fine.

Comment: Restricting use of exceptions to truly unrecoverable errors is a bit much. But you're right that they shouldn't be used for "normal" control flow.

Comment: True... that was a bit harsh on my part.  I'm used to seeing exceptions in cases like I/O failure, network transport errors, etc. where what you're trying to do just isn't going to work and you have to fall back on something else.